# Does the Fundamental theorem of linear algebra extend to Hermitian conjugates (adjoints)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does the Fundamental theorem of linear algebra extend to Hermitian conjugates (adjoints)?

ie. Can I replace the transpose in all the statements [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremofLinearAlgebra.html) with the * (Hermitian Conjugate)?

Comment: Yes, there's no difficulty.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.